# unable to pull data from mysql in angularJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, angularjs

I am very new at angularJS. I have been to show all customers from mysql using. So, I wrote as in cotroller and service as:

```
app.controller('CustomersController', function ($scope, customersService, $http) {

init();

function init() {
    $scope.customers = customersService.getCustomers();
}

});

app.service('customersService', function ($http) {
this.getCustomers = function () {
    return customers;
};
// my issue is here
$http.get("app/server/read.php")
    .success(function(data){
        var customers = data;
    });
});
```

In php I have written:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM customers");
$return_arr = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
$rowArr = array(
    'id' => $row['id'],
    'firstName' => $row['firstname'],
    'lastName' => $row['lastname'],
    'address' => $row['address'],
    'city' => $row['city']
);

$return_arr[] = $rowArr;
}
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

php returns the json array as:

```
[{"id":"36","firstName":"asdasd","lastName":"asdasd","address":"","city":"asdasd"},{"id":"37","firstName":"asdasd","lastName":"asdasd","address":"","city":"asdasd"},{"id":"38","firstName":"asdasd","lastName":"asdasd","address":"","city":"asdasd"},{"id":"39","firstName":"","lastName":"","address":"","city":""},{"id":"40","firstName":"asd","lastName":"asd","address":"","city":"asd"}]
```

I do not understand how to put this json object array into the variable `customers` because when I write directly this array into the variable `customers` it works. i.e.

```
var customers = [{"id":"36","firstName":"asdasd","lastName":"asdasd","address":"","city":"asdasd"},{"id":"37","firstName":"asdasd","lastName":"asdasd","address":"","city":"asdasd"},{"id":"38","firstName":"asdasd","lastName":"asdasd","address":"","city":"asdasd"},{"id":"39","firstName":"","lastName":"","address":"","city":""},{"id":"40","firstName":"asd","lastName":"asd","address":"","city":"asd"}]
```

But I can't put it dynamically that after success of get method result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the `$http` promise from your service and then in the .success callback set your $scope property.

```
app.controller('CustomersController', function ($scope, customersService, $http) {

    init();

function init() {
    customersService.getCustomers().success(function(data){
        $scope.customers = data;
    });
}

});

app.service('customersService', function ($http) {
    this.getCustomers = function () {
        return $http.get("app/server/read.php");
    };
});
```

Comment: if I use in this way `$http.get("app/server/read.php")
    .success(function(data){
        var customers = data;
    });
});`, I found that there is an error that is, customers is not define. Please could you tell me how to define the customers because if I follow your way, other operation is affected.

Comment: var customers defines customers but you don't want to user var, you want to add it to the scope like I do in my answer.

Comment: Yes I understand, but is it possible to pull data from mysql and put into a variable then add it to scope?

Comment: Yes `var something = data; $scope.customers = something;`